# Apple annual testing device limit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, distribution, provisioning

Anyone know when the annual development device limit of 100 for Apple gets reset? Given that in each app development there can be a need to deploy up to 10 to 20 test devices it seems like its pretty easy to bump into this limit over the course of a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only when you renew your developer account you can reset the devices.

> **How do I reset my list of iOS development devices in the iOS
>   Provisioning Portal?**
>
> At the start of your new membership year, Team Agents or Admins can
>   sign in to the iOS Provsioning Portal to remove listed devices and
>   restore the available device count to 100 devices. Be sure to remove
>   all devices you no longer use for development prior to adding any new
>   devices.

from [apple support articles](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html)

Comment: Thanks - its not abundantly clear where or how this is done - does the team agent simply delete every device and voila limit tops back up to 100?  Or are they prompted?  Anyway - thanks for finding doc that I couldn't :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the set of of devices yourself once every 12 months.

So, if you get to 99 devices, you can reset it and clear out the existing list of devices, and then that's it for another 12 months.

This seems like quite a low limit (and one that I'm running into).

The problem is that resetting the list [presumably] invalidates existing ad-hoc provisioning, so  existing beta testers would need to be re-added and update their Beta installations.

Not ideal, imo.

Comment: thanks  - its a good question as to whether the reset would invalidate exiting provisioning profiles - I suspect not - i.e. the device would be able to run the profile until the profile expired, even if the device was deleted from the provisioning portal - which is probably why they don't increase the limit just because you delete a device from the portal.